# Unable to access disk with Arch Linux USB install

Tags: linux, arch-linux, partition, disk

I was trying to install arch linux but I cannot partition my Drive in my computer while booting up with USB arch linux, It doesn't show the disk that I partitioned in windows partition thingy, it only shows the usb's disk. please help

Comment: What's your machine? I'm having the same issue with Dell and the solutions aren't that easy IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing SATA Operation from "RAID" to "AHCI": https://support.thinkcritical.com/kb/articles/switch-windows-10-from-raid-ide-to-ahci

Comment: I don't know how to do it, I got stuck on 
Type this command and press ENTER: bcdedit /set {current} safeboot minimal (ALT: bcdedit /set safeboot minimal)
where it outputed 
Invalid command line switch: /set                                                                                       Run "bcdedit /?" for command line assistance.                                                                           The parameter is incorrect.